# Debian Desktop working inside virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, debian

I installed debian wheezy on a virtual box hard disk but I don't see any desktop icons and things like desktop shorcuts don't work.

I have the latest updates.

How do I fix this?

Comment: you could also consider to dercibe the situation precisely instead of saying thing that don't make sense. please describe your situation , what you want to accomplish, and what is the behavior you get.

Comment: If you don't see icons, how can shortcuts work? WHat shortcuts? Does anything change if you type Alt+F2 and then write `nautilus`?

Comment: @terdon sorry, there are no shortcuts

Comment: Then how would you expect them to work? Please [edit] your question and add more details, as it is we have no idea what you're talking about. Maybe a screenshot? The errors your received when installing? You said the terminal works, did you try running `nautilus` as I suggested? Did you try moving your mouse to the top left corner as PythoNic suggested?

Answer (score 2):

What desktop environment? Gnome comes with a plain desktop. *Move the mouse to the border or the upper right corner. Does it help?* If it doesn't help or it's not Gnome post a screenshot.

Where did you download the installation or virtual machine? 32 or 64 bit?
What size of Hard disk did you use? How much CPU / Ram? Where did you place the virtual box files / snapshots? Local or on network?

Could you copy the error message?

If you get me a link for the virtual machine, I could try it out on my own...

Comment: its gnome its got a debian logo in the desktop. also the right click doesn't do anything :( Also comes with iceweazel

Comment: 64 bit, 30GB, 2GB ram, local

Comment: On install complete, it did moan about not installing correctly. The terminal and browsers and apps work ok

Comment: @FutuToad you might have mentioned that in your question. What did it "moan" about? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: Please avoid using unnecessary formatting, it's your post so do as you like, but it's not appreciated and it makes it harder to read. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194664/203101) and similar discussions. Also, you might want to have a look at our [help]. This post is [not really an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118582/203101), it's just questions for the OP and would have been better as a comment. If you stick around a little, you'll have the [reputation](unix.stackexchange.com/privileges) to leave comments.